# Why latest STS doesn't supprot latest Spring 4.2.4?

Tags: spring, spring-tool-suite, spring-ide

I just downloaded the STS (Spring Tool Suite) and created a simple Spring project.

But the supported Spring version is as below:

[image]

Why the latest `Spring 4.2.4` is not listed? How can I add it?

Answer (score 0):

I think, it's because they are in favor of Spring-boot. You can create a Spring Starter Project instead and it will come with the lastest version of spring.

Comment: The wizard that you mentioned above didn't get updated in the recent releases and provides a way to use Spring 3.x only. In order to get started with Spring 4 projects we indeed strongly encourage you to use Spring Boot and the "Spring Starter Project" wizard. It lets you choose the Spring Boot version (1.3.0 just got released and is based on Spring 4.2.3). It is definitely the best way to write your Spring 4 apps these days.